# What's Qotw Tag All About?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I guess it stands for "Quote of the Week," but what are its origins? What questions does it apply to?

See [qotw](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qotw) for what I'm talking about...

Comment: btw on Meta you can just write [tag:qotw], and it automagically turns it into a hyperlinked tag back to the main site.

Comment: @AviD Cool feature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the early days of mi.yodeya, as a way to demonstrate which content was what we saw as ideal, I did a "[Question of the Week](http://lo.yodeya.com/search/label/qotw)" series on mi.yodeya's site news blog, lo.yodeya. From what I could tell, no one was really reading it, preferring to stick to the real content on the actual site, so I eventually let it go.

The tag probably doesn't make sense to keep at this point.

Comment: I move to delete it.

Comment: @msh210: OK, I'll delete it from a few questions each day for a few days so as not to deluge the front page with all 12 old questions at once.

Comment: IIRC m.y had a delete-a-tag function for moderators. I don't see it here, but perhaps it exists....

Comment: @msh210 IIRC it didn't. I once tried to accomplish this by merging a tag with nothing, and ended up causing errors that had to be corrected by a dev. My understanding is that the only ways to delete a tag are to merge it into something else or to delete it from all questions it's on.

Comment: [tag:qotw] is now gone